# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php

lo he mirado mas de 100 veces alguien ve el error estoy intentando hacer un update

```
public function modificar_producto($datos) {
    $ok = "false";
    $sql = "update productos set "
        . "codigo_articulo=?,"
        . "titulo_producto=?,"
        . "contenido_producto=?,"
        . "precio_producto=?,"
        . "cantidad_disponible=?,"
        . "imagen_producto=?,"
        . "categoria=?"
        . "where id_producto=?";
    $stmt = $this->consulta_prepared($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssiissi",$datos[0], $datos[1], $datos[2],$datos[3],$datos[4],$datos[5],$datos[6],$datos[7]);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt) {
        $ok = "true";
    }
    $arr = array('ok' => $ok);
    return ($arr);
}
```

este es el error que me pasa:

> [13-Feb-2017 05:08:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a
>   member function bind_param() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zona\admin\clases\productos.class.php on line 146

Comment: que es `sssiissi` que le estas pasando a bind_param() ?

Comment: seria el tipo de dato, s string i entero

Comment: bueno, segun lo que estuve investigando, `bind_param` solo devuelve un boolean `FALSE` cuando el `prepare` tuvo un error. Puede ser por que no estas conectado a la base de datos, por que la consulta sql tiene algun campo o tabla que no existe, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El significado de `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean` proviene de no haber tenido en cuenta que `$stmt` podría valer `false` (un valor booleano, no un recurso mysqli) en caso de que se produjera un error en el `prepare`.

Un dato booleano no tiene propiedades ni métodos (como el método llamado `bind_param()` que tratas de usar). De ahí ese mensaje: "no puedes llamar a una función miembro de un dato de tipo booleano".

Puedes averiguar qué falla en tu código si lo blindas correctamente ante situaciones de error. Es una mala práctica (y te provocará situaciones como ésta) no hacerlo.

Obviamente el error proviene de haber concatenado incorrectamente las cadenas de caracteres debido a que `"categoria=?" . "where id_producto=?"` da como resultado `"categoria=?where id_producto=?"`, un error de sintaxis SQL.

En el siguiente ejemplo te muestro cómo blindar tu código ante condiciones de error y evitar la concatenación de cadenas, propensas a este tipo de errores:

```
public function modificar_producto($datos) {
    /* No es necesario concatenar cadenas, se puede hacer de esta manera */
    $sql = '
      UPDATE productos SET
        codigo_articulo=?,
        titulo_producto=?,
        contenido_producto=?,
        precio_producto=?,
        cantidad_disponible=?,
        imagen_producto=?,
        categoria=?
      WHERE id_producto=?
    ';
    $stmt = $this->consulta_prepared($sql);
    /* Comprobamos si la preparación se finalizó con éxito o hubo error */
    if ($stmt === false) {
        /* Puedes hacer un return con ok a false o lanzar una excepción */
        /*throw new Exception('Error en prepare: ' . $stmt->error);*/
        return [ 'ok' => 'false' ];
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('sssiissi',
      $datos[0],
      $datos[1],
      $datos[2],
      $datos[3],
      $datos[4],
      $datos[5],
      $datos[6],
      $datos[7]
    );
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt === false) {
        /* De nuevo puedes lanzar una excepción o devolver un error */
        /*throw new Exception('Error en execute: ' . $stmt->error);*/
        return [ 'ok' => 'false' ];
    } else {
        return [ 'ok' => 'true' ];
    }
}
```

Yo, personalmente, prefiero el uso de excepciones. Cuando llames a la función `modificar_producto` puedes controlar una condición de error de manera sencilla:

```
try {
  modificar_producto($datos);
  /* Todo fue OK si llegamos a esta línea */
} catch (Exception $e) {
  /* Podemos finalizar la ejecución con un mensaje o mostrar HTML con él */
  die('Error modificando producto: ' .  $e->getMessage());
}
```

Devolver una matriz con un elemento `ok` a `true` o `false` te impedirá o dificultará depurar el origen del error.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en que  $`this->consulta_prepared($sql)` devuelve siempre `false` ya que tu consulta no es correcta sintacticamente al faltarle un espacio antes del where (estas concatenando la variable ? con where).

Básicamente estas haciendo: `Update productos set categoria=?where id_producto = ?`

Pon siempre un espacio al principio y al final de cada linea entre `""` y así no te dará nunca ese error.

```
$sql = " update productos set "
    . " codigo_articulo=?, "
    . " titulo_producto=?, "
    . " contenido_producto=?, "
    . " precio_producto=?, "
    . " cantidad_disponible=?, "
    . " imagen_producto=?, "
    . " categoria=? "
    . " where id_producto=? ";
```

Comment: Solucionado al 1000%