# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando una pagina donde se consulte informacion de una base de datos asi como borrar la respectiva fila, pero al hacer el button de Delete me manda el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in
>   C:\AppServ\www\crud\index.php on line 28

La conexion es con sql server por lo que he buscado ejemplos pero todos son para Mysqli entonces estoy abierto a comentarios.
Ya trate de hacer un sqlsrv_query(conn,dQuery) directo pero tampoco soluciono el problema, tambien estoy creyendo que pueda ser como obtenga el id del button pero la verdad no sabria

```
<?php
$serverName = 'SNMXLAP187\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"prueba");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM AREAS";
$sResult = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sQuery)


?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['area'])){
        $area = $_POST['area'];
        $iQuery = "INSERT INTO prueba.dbo.AREAS(AREA)
        values('$area')";
        $sqlRes=sqlsrv_query($conn,$iQuery);
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $id = $_POST['delete'];
    $dQuery = "DELETE FROM AREAS WHERE ID = ? "; 
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $dQuery);
    $stmt->bindParam("i", $id);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-2 mb-4 p-2 shadow bg-white">
        <form  method="POST">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <input type="text" required name="area" class="form-control" id="area" placeholder="Ingrese Area">
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-info">Agregar Area</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Area</th>
                    <th></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <form method="POST">
                    <?php                     
                    #Codigo para dezplegar la BD
                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sResult,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)): 
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $row['ID']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['AREA']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type ="submit" name="delete" value="<?= $row['id'];?>" class= "btn btn-danger">Delete</button>     
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </form>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Puede ser que sea un tipo de variable no esperado en $stmt->bindParam("i", $id);` comprueba que `$id` tiene el tipo de variable esperado. Puedes probarlo con `var_dump(gettype($id));`  Mira este hilo tienen el mismo problema... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49131/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-boolean

Comment: @EduardPinuaga gracias a tu comentario me puse a checar que la pagian que se dezplegaba en el navegador y mi error era que el boton nunca tenia valor debido a que a la hora de generase el boton el ID no era extraido de la base de datos porque lo tenia escrito en minusculas..... No pense que fuera relevante a la hora de consultar pero ya vi que si .