# Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Tags: php

necesito su aydua para resolver este error de PHP, consiste en el error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool.

De antemano agradezco sus comentarios, respuestas y recomendaciones.

Codigo:

```
 function registraUsuario($usuario, $password, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario){

global $mysqli;
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","login");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, password, email, activacion, token, tipo_usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $nombre, $usuario, $password, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario);

if ($stmt->execute()){
  return $mysqli->insert_id;
  } else {
  return 0; 
}
```

}

Y esta es la llamada a la función:

```
$registro = registraUsuario($usuario, $password, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario);
```

Comment: Tras el `prepare(...)` haz un `if ($stmt === false) { die($mysqli->error); }` y nos dices qué mensaje de error te muestra. Ese error te sale porque `$stmt` vale `false` (booleano) porque hubo un error y no lo estás gestionando.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver con phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Shaz , hay gente que piensa que phpmyadmin es lo mismo que mysql (porque es lo que ven al gestionar la base de datos). Tienes reputación suficiente para editar las etiquetas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind\_param() on boolean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49131/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-boolean). Es lo mismo que te he puesto en el primer comentario, el problema está en que el `prepare` ha fallado, ha devuelto `false` y no se puede acceder a un método de un valor booleano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error *`Call to a member function bind_param() on bool.`*  significa que el objeto que está invocando a  `bind_param` es un booleano.

En tu código ese objeto es `$stmt` y esto ocurre siempre que la llamada a `prepare` falla por algún motivo. Esto puede ser por error de sintaxis en la consulta, porque la conexión es nula o por otro motivo.

Propondría que escribas un código totalmente controlado, verificando el estado de cada cosa. En este escenario al menos tres aspectos deberían cubrirse:

1. Que la conexión no es nula
2. Que la preparación fue exitosa
3. Que la ejecución fue exitosa

En este ejemplo, en vez de un valor simple vamos a retornar un array con dos claves posibles: `error` o `done`. Y en el valor de ellas, retornamos el `id` en el caso de `done` o el mensaje de error en caso de error. Así damos coherencia al código.

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $password, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario){
    //global $mysqli; #Evita el uso de globales si es posible
    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","login");
    if ($mysqli) { #1
        $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, password, email, activacion, token, tipo_usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) { #2
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $nombre, $usuario, $password, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario);
            if ($stmt->execute()){ #3
                return array ("done"=>$mysqli->insert_id);
            } else {
                return array("error"=>"Error en execute"); 
            } 
        } else {
            return array("error"=>"Error preparando la consulta");  
        }     
    } else {
        return array("error"=>"Conexión no válida");
    }
}
```

### Cambio en la llamada

Dado que ahora la función devuelve un array, hay que dar coherencia en la llamada haciendo algo como esto:

```
$mData=registrarUsuario( ... parametros ...);
if ( isset($mData["error"]) ) {
    /*
      Manejo contextual para el caso de error
      Se podría por ejemplo recuperar el mensaje de error y mostrarlo
    */
    $msgError=$mData["error"];
    echo $msgError;

} else {
    /*
      Manejo contextual para el caso de éxito
      Recuperamos el $id que estaria en done y operamos con él
    */
    $id=$mData["done"];
}
```

Se podría pensar que hacer todo esto es más rollo y más largo. El código tiene que ser robusto y controlar todas las eventualidades. No se puede programar pensando que *siempre todo irá bien*. Hay que ser más bien *pesimista* cuando programas, pensando que todo podría ir mal y cuando eso ocurra tienes que estar ahí para controlarlo.