# Error al intentar leer datos de una base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Hola
Yo tengo el seguiente código PHP, con el que se deberían seleccionar las filas con el nombre **testname** de mi base de datos:

```
  $select = $connection_conn -> prepare("SELECT content FROM images WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1");
  $select -> bindParam(':name', 'testname');
  $select -> execute();
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\miproyecto\database-test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\miproyecto\database-test.php on line 6

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Esto probablemente responda tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128761/177597

Comment: El error indica que `$select` es un booleano. Eso ocurre cuando `prepare()` ha fallado. En este contexto solo dos cosas pueden causar ese fallo: 1. La conexión es nula; 2. Error en la instrucción SQL (tabla o columna no existen). @Adrián la pregunta enlazada es sobre mysqli, y esta es sobre PDO. Aunque la causa del problema es parecido el código es distinto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error *`Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean`* indica que el objeto con el que intentas llamar a `bindParam()` es un booleano, hablamos de `$select` en este caso:

```
$select -> bindParam(':name', 'testname');
```

Tienes entonces que revisar dónde has creado a `$select`:

```
  $select = $connection_conn -> prepare("SELECT content FROM images WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1");
```

Ha sido preparando una consulta con `prepare()`. El Manual de PHP dice que este método devuelve un `PDOStatement` si no hay error, **o `FALSE` (booleano) si hay error**. Por tanto, en tu preparación hay un error que puede deberse a dos motivos:

1. La conexión es nula
2. La consulta SQL es errónea (tabla o columna no existen)

Para evitar esto, conviene controlar en el código todo lo que pueda salir mal. Por ejemplo:

```
#Verificamos la conexión
if( $connection_conn )
{
    #Podemos usar un if al crear $select
    if ( $select = $connection_conn -> prepare("SELECT content FROM images WHERE name=:name LIMIT 1") ) 
    {
        $select -> bindParam(':name', 'testname');
        $select -> execute();
        #Resto del código
    } else {
        echo "Error de instrucción SQL. Comprueba que tablas/columnas existen";
    }
} else {
    echo "No hay conexión. Revisa credenciales, etc";
}
```

Es un ejemplo de código robusto, donde prevees todos los posibles fallos, controlando el flujo e informando adecuadamente. En contextos donde se espera un retorno, conviene usar una sola variable emitiendo su resultado en el `return`.