# Verificar si un email existe en la base de datos: PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, funciones, email

Esta es la funcion que estoy utilizando

```php
function emailExiste($email){

    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if ($num > 0){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Pero al correlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindparam() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi-pagina\DBusuarios.php:62 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi-pagina\registrate.php(29): emailExiste('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi-pagina\DBusuarios.php on line 62
```

La linea 62 es el "bind_param()"

Alguien podría orientarme sobre como resolverlo? Soy muy nueva en esto, es la primera que lo hago.

Comment: Esto `bindparam` está mal escrito debe ser así `bind_param`

Comment: Gracias, justo lo acabo de cambiar y continua el mismo error

Comment: Si, por otro lado si haces `var_dump($mysqli);` que obtienes?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind\_param() on boolean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49131/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error: *`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool ...`*  está indicando que el objeto sobre el que quieres invocar a `bind_param` es un booleano.

Lo que ocurre en este caso es que `$stmt` es `false` (booleano) y no un objeto Prepared Statement que es lo que debería ser.

Y, ¿por qué es `false`? Pues porque **algo ha fallado** en el código. Por tanto, debes controlar todo aquello que pueda fallar, escribiendo así un programa robusto que te informará en todo momento de la situación.

Vamos a ello:

```
function emailExiste($email){

    global $mysqli;
    /*
     *1. Controlamos que haya conexión
    */
    if($mysqli) {
        #Para este caso es mejor usar COUNT
        $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ? LIMIT 1";
        /*
         *2. Controlamos la preparación
        */
        if( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            #Se agrega el resultado de COUNT a $num
            $stmt->bind_result($num);
            $stmt->close();
            #Se puede usar operador de comparación
            $mData=array( 'msg'=>'success', 'status'=>($num > 0) );
        } else {
            $mData=array('msg'=>'Error preparando: '.$mysqli->error,'status'=>false);
        }
    } else {
        $mData=array('msg'=>'Error de conexión','status'=>false);        
    }
    return $mData;
}
```

En la llamada del método puedes hacer un `var_dump` o leer la clave `msg` del mismo. Yo he usado para este caso un array `$mData` donde voy poniendo en la clave 'msg' un eventual mensaje (sobre todo para los errores) y en la clave 'status' el booleano que pudieras necesitar. Es algo que he hecho ad libitum pero que puedes modificar a tu gusto.

Si no entiendes algo puedes decirlo en comentarios.