# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in realizando un INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Tratando de realizar un `INSERT` me genera el siguiente error en la línea del `bind_param`.
No se si sea por los campos del formulario que traje con el `foreach` (los que están en la variable `$k`) porque los cambies después de que al principio me salía el error *Array to sting conversion* entonces lo deje así como esta ahora.

Este es el error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeria\save_form.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeria\save_form.php on line 33

Este es el código:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'conn.php';
    $con = conectarDb();
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
        $campos_ads='';
        foreach($_POST as $k=>$v ) {
    
                $campos_ads.= $k.',';
    
            }
            $campos_ads=substr_replace($campos_ads, "", -1);
        $params=array();
       
        $ins_q='INSERT INTO ads (';
        $query=$campos_ads.') VALUES(';
        $sql=$ins_q.$query;
        foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
      
              $params[] = !empty($v) ? $v : "";
              $sql.="?,";
     
        }
    
        $sql=substr_replace($sql, "", -1).")";
        
        $types="isssssssdssss";
    
    
        echo $sql;
        $ins= $con->prepare($sql);
        $ins->bind_param($types,...$params);    
        if ($ins->execute()) {
            $header="";
        } else {
            $header="";
        }
          
        $ins->close();
        $con->close();
      } else {
        $header="";
      }
      header($header);
      exit;

?>
```

No se si es por la conversión de tipo de datos pero si alguien sabe como puedo hacer que funcione le agradeciera!

esto son los echo de:

```
Echo de $sql
INSERT INTO ads (ads_id,ads_title,ads_content,key-1,key-2,key-3,ads_price,ads_owner,ads_tel,ads_email,ads_data) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

echo de $types

isssssssdssss

print_r de $params

Array ( [0] => [1] => primer as [2] => sdsdsds [3] => sd [4] => sd [5] => sd [6] => 25055 [7] => NANO [8] => 5785885 [9] => DEMO@DEMO.COM [10] => 2021-10-06 10:28:13 )
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a esta otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49131/5896 Sería interesante que pegaras aquí la consulta que te está mostrando el echo, puede ser que esté mal construida.

Comment: Vale,  ya he editado la publicación mostrando lo que hay en las variables pero a simple vista no entiendo por que sale en este caso. Ya he validado y los campos del formulario están igual que en la DB y los tipos de datos están correctos. Creo que tiene que ver con la variable $campos_ads pero al usar var_dump para ver el tipo de datos, dice que es un string (93)  y ahí si no se que mas pueda ser... Voy a ver si algo de lo que dicen en esa pregunta me sirve pero ya he visto varios temas pero nada. le echare un vistazo mejor gracias.

Comment: "key-1,key-2,key-3" Son nombres o operaciones?

Comment: son nombres pero ahora que lo mencionas si veo algo raro en los numeros -.-".

Comment: Ok solucionado cambiado los nombres del formulario y en la DB. Gracias por la observación bro!